# datatable tfoot input select server side search

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi I am using ajax to populate the datatable with paging but using the example below to populate input select for filtering, it only populates the dropdown list with ones found on the current page. Therefore I populates the tfoot section from the server side.

https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

However, in order to assign the on change event, i still tried using the initComplete method as below .. but it doesn't seem like to get to on change event. is there something i did wrong .. ?

```
            "initComplete": function () {
            this.api().columns([1]).every(function () {
                var column = this;

                console.log(this.value);
                $('input', this.footer()).on('change', function (e) {
                    column.search(this.value).draw();
                });
            });
```

The html for tfoot that server sides generates is as below.

```
 <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th>
                            <select class="form-control input-sm">
                            <option value=""></option><option value="1">a</option>
                            <option value="2">b</option>
                            <option value="3">c</option>
                            <option value="4">d</option>
                            <option value="5">e</option>                                
                            </select>
                        </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
```

Comment: You ask [numerous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2274411/superted?tab=questions) and you're getting some good answers but has not accepted almost all of them. I answered two of your questions with no feedback. Cooperating will increase your chances for a good answer. I'm skipping this one.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use the below code to get this working...

```
 "initComplete": function () {

            this.api().columns([1]).every(function () {
                var column = this;
                console.log($('select', this.footer()));
                $('select', this.footer()).on('change', function () {
                    alert('reach here');
                    console.log($(this).val());
                    var val = $(this).val();
                    column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();

                });

            });
```